# module is not defined and process is not defined in eslint in visual studio code

Tags: module, process, eslint

I have installed eslint in my machine and i have used visual studio code
i have certain modules and process to be exported
When i try to use "module" or "process" it shows 
it was working fine before.

```
[eslint] 'module' is not defined. (no-undef)
[eslint] 'process' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

and here is my .eslintrc.json

```
{

"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true

},
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  },
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "windows"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ]
}
```

}

I want to remove this error

Comment: I have found it thanks. 
we need to add 

"globals": {
        "angular": false,
        "module": false,
        "inject": false,
        "document": false
      },

"env": {
        "browser": true,
        "amd": true,
        "node": true
    }

in the .eslintrc.json file

Comment: Thanks :) This worked for me. You should put that as an answer with a quick example.

Answer (score 321):

You are probably trying to run this in node environment.

The `env` section should look like this:

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true,
    "node": true
},
```

Comment: Note: This needs to go in your .eslintrc file

Comment: The `browser` and `amd` parts of this config are not needed to solve this particular error.

Comment: this should be the right answer

Comment: It creates the `"browser"` entry even if I chose "Node" in the setup process. Weird.

Answer (score 156):

In your ESLint config file, simply add this:

```
{
  ...
  env: {
    node: true
  }
  ...
}
```

That should fix the `"module" is not defined` and `"process" is not defined` error.

> That assumes you are running in a Node environment. There is also the `browser` option for a browser environment. You can apply both based on your need.

If you want to prevent ESLint from linting some globals then you will need to add the specific global variables in the `globals` section of the config.

```
globals: {
  window: true,
  module: true
}
```

Answer (score 90):

You need to [tell eslint that you are in a Node environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments). My favourite way to do this for one-off files like `gulpfile.js` is to include this comment at the top:

```
/* eslint-env node */
```

Comment: Perfect solution for frontend code, where globally specifying this is obviously wrong. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Eliminates the problem in the most direct and objective way.

Comment: Accepted answer is way too broad, you don't want to allow node syntax everywhere, just in the one file.

Comment: This is a very simple solution and also simply explained.

Comment: Can't you just add `overrides` to your `eslintrc.cjs` to match all files that end in `*.cjs` to have `env: { node: true }` and then rename all your CommonJS files to end in `.cjs`? Is it bad?

Comment: @Seangle If you have a lot of files, it is a valid option. but in this case, this is an easier option: the file itself decides how to deal with lint, and in a frontend project, you usually have only a couple of config files that may be written in the node module style

Answer (score 7):

You can just rename all your CommonJS files to have `.cjs` as their extension and then add `node: true` into the `overrides` of `.cjs` files to `eslintrc.cjs`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  env: {
    es2023: true,
    // If you don't want to add `node: true` globally...
  },
    // ...then add `overrides`:
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.cjs'],
      env: {
        es2023: true,
        node: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

---

### Edit

On a side note, I think have to highlight the importance of being aware of what runtime environments are and then how your bundler is configured. For that I suggest reading:

- [ESLint Docs on environments](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments)
- [Introduction to Javascript runtime environments](https://www.codecademy.com/article/introduction-to-javascript-runtime-environments)
- [Vite specific transpiling, Typescript, ESBuild, NPM Modules](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html)

Understanding these concepts will prevent a lot of potential errors and as a bonus will make you able to configure ESLint however you want with a lot of flexibility without having to search for specific ready configs.

Comment: i go with this approach

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me for a new project in 2023. Specifically, I needed `overrides` for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

in my .eslintrc.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  env: { browser: true,es2020: true },
   /*rest of code goes here*/
}
```

i've added node property to the env object and set it to true `node: true`
so the final result would be

```
module.exports = {
  env: { browser: true, node: true, es2020: true },
   /*rest of code goes here*/
}
```

and now there's no issue

Comment: Wait until you see `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'process')` in production in your browser and your ESLint doesn't see any issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case below codes solve the issues

eslintrc.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true,es2022: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.cjs'],
      env: {
        node: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 'latest', sourceType: 'module' },
  settings: { react: { version: '18.2' } },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': 'warn',
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  },
}
```