# ESLint 'module' is not defined. (no-undef) into PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, eslint, eslintrc

In PhpStorm I have this error in my .eslintrc file :

```
ESLint 'module' is not defined. (no-undef) into PHPStorm
```

I already try to fix it using [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789177/module-is-not-defined-and-process-is-not-defined-in-eslint-in-visual-studio-code). But the result is the same. ESLint error appears again.

**This is my .eslintrc file:**

```
/* eslint-env node */
{
  "root": false,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "amd": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/base",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "error",
    "no-debugger": "error",
    "no-unused-components": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-empty-function": "off",
    "prefer-const": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
        "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
      ],
      "env": {
        "mocha": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Perhaps it's a PhpStorm issue ?*

*How to resolve this error ESLint ?*

Comment: can't reproduce when using your config. Is it the only eslint configuration file in your project? Could you share a code snippet the issue is reported against plus a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete 'es6': 'true',
just like:

```
"env": {
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "commonjs": true,
  "amd": true
}
```